# Is Dead-end filling algorithm to find output in a maze considered as a backtracking algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I am new to backtracking problems and stumbled upon this maze problem. There are lots of solution to solve maze problem. But I was wondering about dead-end filling problem.

Answer (score 2):

The first step of this algorithm is to find all dead-ends. To achieve this the algorithm will traverse through the maze like through a matrix and mark all floors with 3 walls, say by putting them onto a stack. So this loop clearly isn't backtracking.

The second step consists of filling up the dead-ends until a junction is met. This is done by fetching a dead-end from the stack and working along the corridor. Still no backtracking.

The final step is already the solution, a path from entry to exit. Traversing this, if needed, is trivial. So this algorithm is neither recursive nor backtracking.

Comment: After filling all dead-ends there can still be a maze with more than one path left. think of circles!

Comment: To make it clear: Using a stack is no argument that it is not backtracking. Backtracking can be implemented without recursion by just using a stack.

Comment: There are surely mazes that cannot be solved by this, but I think this doesn't change the nature of this algorithm. It's not trial and error so to say. (looked that up, I admit)